Как применить xsl к xml?
Мне нужно преобразовать xml с помощью xslt.
Например, я создал файл с шаблоном преобразования cd_catalog.xsl для преобразования cd_catalog.xsl. Оба файла находятся в одном каталоге.
В cd_catalog.xsl я добавил , т.е.:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cd_catalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>

Хочу проверить и открываю его в браузере. Похоже что это не правильно. Как можно и лучше смотреть и тестировать применение этого xsl ?

Возможно браузер блокирует запуск локальных xsl (почему?). Включение фулл доступа к файлам выглядит как костыль. Хотелось бы более профессиональных решений)

Вам нужен XSL трансформер, движок который выполнит преобразование. Можно найти онлайн версию, без установок.

т.е. в браузере это фигня сработает?

XSL трансформер, например?

https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

@Komdosh спасибо за ответ.

Я почему-то был уверен что этот трансформер должен входить в базовый набор инструментов для разработчика. Получается все онлайн сервисами пользуются?!

В инете вообще ничего об этом нет

«Похоже что это не правильно» — о чём речь?

Вы чем пользуетесь для написания XML? Вряд ли простым текстовым редактором наподобие Notepad. Вот там и смотрите средства для работы с XSLT. Если их нет, то ищите специализированные IDE для работы с XML/XSLT, типа Oxygen, Altova и пр. Также во многие IDE встроены такие средства. Например, Visual Studio (прадва, уже устаревшие, да и весит она...) Ко многим средам есть плагины.

Ну так странно что по href="http://example.com/xslt.xls" оно работает (ну или должно работать), а локально нет. Локально вроде в IE должно работать, но я не проверял.
